# strpos() Returning wrong result

Tags: php, strpos

My issue is I have two numbers in the array  5,12 my issue is the code below is returning "1" as true because of the "1" in number 12- it sees the number 1 in 12. How do I tell it to read the ENTIRE number.

```
<?php 
$pos = strpos($foo,"1");

if($pos === false) {
    // do this if its false
    echo "<img src='../PICS/no.png' width='20' height='20' />"; 
}
else {
    echo "<img src='../PICS/yes.png' width='20' height='20' />"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: so $foo is an array of numbers?

Comment: strpos() is for strings, not numbers or arrays.

Comment: Maybe you want [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) instead

Comment: would `if (in_array("1", $foo)) {` work?

Comment: if your checking an array for a value use in_array();

Comment: why the hell do you write a **so** in the starting?

Comment: $foo is the call to a table result- in this case the table column contains 5,12 .

Comment: strcmp does not work- just tried it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the signature for the function you are using:

> int strpos ( **string** $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )

If you are feeding it with a array as first argument...

```
<?php
$foo = array(5,12);
$pos = strpos($foo,"1");
```

... the array will be cast to string and you'll get a notice...

> Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

The resulting string will contain "Array", literally:

```
var_dump( @(string)array(5,12) ); // string(5) "Array"
```

And your search for `1` will always fail because `Array` does not contain it.

Answer (score 3):

Use **[`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)**

```
if (in_array(1,$myarray)){
    // found in the array
}
```